# $pdo->lastInsertId(); Возможно ли некорректное значение?

Tags: php

Допустим имеем такой код:

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES (:email,:password)");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
$_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Если бы я вызывал метод `lastInsertId()` у `$stmt`, то не задался бы следующим вопросом:

`lastInsertId()` берет значение последнего `id` у объекта подключения к БД. Может ли случится такая ситуация, что из за нагрузки или чего либо другого `$pdo->lastInsertId()` вернет `id` следующего после регистрации пользователя, т.к. первому еще не успел взять значение `id` а второй уже прошел регистрацию и записал данные в базу. И следовательно в `$pdo` обновилось значение последнего `id`.

Comment: как по мне я бы после регистрации авторизовывал бы по имени и паролю. что бы исключить такие сомнения

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря не должно, `lastInsertId()` возвращает значение именно для последнего вставленного значения, для текущей сессии/соединения. Другие сессии/соединения никак не могу влиять на это значение. И ваш `lastInsertId()` не может попасть в параллельные сессии. Одновременно могут вставляться сотни строк, вы получите идентификатор именно вашего последнего INSERT-запроса.